# Modal only displaying the first image in php

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

The code allows for images to be shown from a list for both two different images. The problem is that when any image with the id frontid and backid is clicked, they display the first image only.I saw using getElementByClassName() as an option but I don't know how to go about this.
Would adding JavaScript to get the class name and make an array be easier?
Here's the code:

````
<?php 
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from upload WHERE status = 0")
or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $name1=$row['name1'];
        $your_phone=$row['msisdn'];
        $customer_id=$row['customerid'];
        $date=$row['date'];
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['name1'] ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['msisdn'] ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['customerid'] ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
            <img class="front-img" src="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>"/>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
        <img class="back-img" src="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name1;?>"/>
        </a>
        </td>
        <!-- Front ID Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Front ID Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Front of ID</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="front-img-modal" src="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>"/>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Back ID Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">          <!-- Back ID Modal content-->
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Back of ID</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <img id="back-img-modal" src="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name1;?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>```
````

Comment: You don't seem to have the usual problem of duplicated element IDs, so I am not sure what exactly the issue is supposed to be here. Can you clarify what you mean by _"calls the first image in a list but all the other images are shown within the list"_?

Comment: The list shows all the images that are stored, but when you click it to open in a modal, the image that is displayed first appears on all the listed images.

Comment: So what are the values of $name and $name1? What does the generated HTML actually look like, are the _correct_ images in the correct locations in there?

Comment: $name and $name1 are the images for frontid and backid respectively. I edited the code to add more context.

Comment: Okay, if this is all inside a loop, then you _do_ have the problem of duplicate IDs here after all. You need to give each modal a _unique_ ID, not repeat the same ones multiple times. Use a loop counter variable, or the database row id, and append that as a suffix to the IDs you are generating there.

Comment: And I don't know how "real" the code above is now, or what parts you might have left out - but if you really have `</td>` followed by `<div>`, that would be invalid HTML. TR can not have DIV as a child element. You need to stick this into a TD, or place it outside of the table, somewhere after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the target and Id get a unique number in the attribute as shown below.

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/'. $inv->image_location) }}"                                          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_{{ $inv->id }}">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_{{ $inv->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Always format the code. It's more readable.